# Does InstallShield keep a log during installation?

Tags: windows, installation

Just want to know if InstallShield keeps a log during installation of an application.

I already checked C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{GUID}, but there isn't a log file there.

The reason is that the installation of a 3rd party tool is failing with an arbitrary error such as:

> "The following error occurred on file \ZZZ. 
>   File is readonly"

Options are: Ignore, Retry, Abort

I want to find out the complete path to the file as well as other information and I think this might be on the log (if there's any).

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [Setup.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://web.archive.org/web/20100427182627/http://documentation.installshield.com/robo/projects/installshield12helplib/ihelpsetup_execmdline.htm) for the official docs on Installshield's command line parameters.

If you're running a `setup.exe` rather than an MSI file, and are running it silently then you can [use the /f2 parameter to specify the log file location](http://web.archive.org/web/20100506075032/http://documentation.installshield.com/robo/projects/installshield12helplib/SetupLog.htm). Something like:

```
Setup.exe /s /f2"C:\Setup.log"
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. 
Can't vote you up cause I don't have reputation, but I promise I will. Thanks.

Comment: This log only shows the following information:[Application]
Name=Sample App 3000
Version=1.00.0000
Company=Sample Software Corporation
Lang=0409
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=0.  Perhaps you want /debuglog

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No logfile is created.

Comment: The `/s` switch disables the wizard UI, which may or may not be what one wants, but it has nothing to do with logging.

Answer (score 27):

There are two components at play - Installshield's engine and the MSIExec/Windows Installer engine.

In later versions of Installshield's Setup.exe bootstrapper, the /debuglog flag was introduced.

To log both, try:

```
Setup.exe /debuglog"C:\PathToLog\setupexe.log" /V"/L*v c:\PathToLog\SetupMSI.log"
```

Make sure the user has write permissions to the paths specified

**Installshield Setup.exe command line**

[2008 Command line reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/install_guide12.htm)

[2009 Command line reference](http://blog.wisefaq.com/2009/01/07/all-about-installshield-command-line-switches/)
   I'm not sure if this is correct as the original is no longer available.

[(dead) 2010 Command line reference](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#wp1039960)

[(dead) 2011 Command line reference](http://helpnet.installshield.com/isxhelp17/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm)

[(dead) 2012 Command line reference](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/ihelpsetup_execmdline.htm)

[Latest command line parameters](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/INFO/Setup-exe-Command-Line-Parameters)

[MSI command line debugging reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_SetLogging)

Also see this 
http://www.installationdeveloper.com/686/using-log-files-in-installshield/

Comment: This worked for me whereas GAThrawn's answer (accepted) did not. (setup.exe built by Visual Studio 2013/Installshield Limited Edition)

Comment: Many dead links here.

Comment: @Agostino three dead links - all Installshield (surprise surprise). Updated the post with the latest command line link from IS.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using the Internet Archive Wayback Machine to fix them?

Answer (score 9):

Also available for installshield Setup.Exe is the /V switch.

```
Setup.exe /V"/LIME c:\Temp\Install.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can force it to have one:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

Comment: That's for MSI. The question is about InstallShield.